# Absolute value of integral equal to integral of absolute value

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, solution-verification

I tried to prove this, however I'm not sure if I did it right. Suppose
$$\left|\int f d\lambda\right|=\int|f| d\lambda$$
then $f\leq 0$ or $f\geq0$

**My proof:**
Suppose $f < 0$ then $f=-|f|$, so
$$-\int fd\lambda=\int |f| d\lambda=\left|\int fd\lambda\right|$$
Since those numbers are positive, then $-f \geq 0$ a.e.

Is it right and do I have to suppose that $f>0$?

Comment: Which measure is $\lambda$? The Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes, it is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: No because you are assuming what you want prove. The goal is to show that $f$ cannot change sign a.e.

Comment: $A \implies B \vee C$ is equivalent to $(A \wedge \neg B) \implies C$

Comment: If it is Lebesgue measure, what is the meaning of $f \ge0$ ?

Comment: The negation of $f \ge 0$ is not $f \lt 0$

Comment: The meaning of $f \geq 0$ is the function is positive for every $x$ in the domain.

Comment: What is the negation of $f \geq 0$?

Comment: It is that $f<0$ somewhere, but not necessarily (almost) everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are proving the converse of what you are asked to prove.

If $\int f d\lambda \geq 0$ then we get $\int (|f|-f)d\lambda=0$. But $|f|-f \geq 0$. If the integral of  a non-negative measurable function is $0$ then  the function is $0$ a.e. Hence $|f|-f =0$ a.e. so $f=|f| \geq 0$ a.e. When $\int f d\lambda < 0$ the argument is similar. Consider $|f|+f$ instead of $|f|-f$.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer.